# How to kill children java processes invoked by a .bat script

Tags: batch-file

I got a .bat script that looks like this

```
START CMD /K java --jar myJar1.jar
START java -jar myJar2.jar
...
(Kill what was invoked by START)
```

I am curious on how one would go about to kill the processes launched by the Jar files, how would one go about to solve it?

Comment: perhaps... `start "MyTitle" java -jar myJar2.jar` and then using `taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq MyTitle"`

Comment: Why not just let them to terminate normally?

Comment: @Alejandro I would guess simply because some jar files do not terminate, unless manually closed/exited. Or perhaps the set of processes do not work as intended, kill all and retry..

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Your solution worked like a charm, if you add it as an answer I will acccept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply start your java instances with a Window title, then kill it according to the same title, as an example:

```
start "MyTitle" java -jar myJar2.jar
....
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq MyTitle"
```